# Make a Column force Container to be same size as other widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

A DartPad example is here: https://dartpad.dev/cf6ab1d34f5b1022aa48ea8ced193de5.

I am trying to make a fraction display, but I cannot get the container that is the fraction bar to not expand to the entire screen. This is the code I have right now:

```
Center(
   child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
          Text("100"),
          Container(
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Text("300"),
       ],
    ),
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html):

```dart
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("100"),
      Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      Text("300"),
    ],
  ),
)
```